# mPDF - Execute PHP code and save it as pdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I found many questions about this topic, but there are no real answers. Does anyone know how to execute PHP script and save result in PDF using mPDF or any other library?

There is no problem when I have static HTML, but I can't do it when I need some server side processing and then save that result as PDF. Basically, I need to display .svg images in specific order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used wkhtmltopdf for such things. which is an application not a library.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

But i dont see what makes the difference between php and standard html .
you can allways file_get_contents('http://server.com/script.php'); 
Then you can save this data as a html and do as you please with it.

Comment: I tried with file_get_contents but it only displays php as plain text, it doesn't execute it. I will try your app

Comment: sorry, i misunderstud you... the file_get_contents() solution is if you need "server side" (understud as remote) processing. If your php is local then, you could exec('./localscript.php > file.html'); (given than the executable bit and the "#!/usr/bin/php" is properly set) and then process the html further.